# How should I start QML files?

Tags: qt, qml

I have 4 QML files: `MainMenu.qml`, `AppArea.qml`, `Result.qml` and `main.qml`.

When my app starts, I want to see first page as `MainMenu.qml` fullscreen. There is a button (on `MainMenu.qml`) to start `AppArea.qml`. When I click the the button, I want to start `AppArea.qml` as fullscreen new window.

There is a button (on `AppArea.qml`), when I click that button, I want to show `Result.qml` but I want to see `Result.qml` on `AppArea.qml`, I mean when `Result.qml` come outs, `AppArea.qml` will not disappear but `Result.qml` will appear on `AppArea.qml`.

There is a button on `Result.qml`. When I click the button, the `Repeater` in `AppArea.qml` will regenerate, because maybe `model` of `Repeater` changing like `1, 2, 3, 4...`. There is a button on `AppArea.qml`, when I click the button, I want to open `MainMenu.qml` as a fullscreen new window like `AppArea.qml`.

Actually you can think basic: My app is a game like this:

[image: mainmenu.png]
[image: App_Area.png]
[image: Resulton_App_Area.png]

How way should I choose for these jobs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a QML Window when opening a other QML Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271781/how-to-hide-a-qml-window-when-opening-a-other-qml-window)

Comment: It would be better also to limit your question to only one problem. In SO multiple issues in same post should be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271781/how-to-hide-a-qml-window-when-opening-a-other-qml-window), in your case you are using the `component` from qml file, so you need to load the `component` first, your `main.qml` can be like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    title: "Main window"
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    Loader{
        id: mainMenuLoader
    }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            mainMenuLoader.source="mainMenu.qml"
            var mainMenu = mainMenuLoader.item.createObject(mainWindow);
            mainWindow.hide()
    }

}
```

and your `mainMenu.qml` can look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Component {
    id:  mainMenu
    Window {
        id:mmenu
        title: "Main Menu"
        width: 600
        height: 600
        visible: true
        flags: Qt.Dialog
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        Loader{
            id: appAreaLoader
        }
        Text {
            text: "This is mainMenu"
        }
        Button{
            id: loadAppArea
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Start Game"
            onClicked: {
                appAreaLoader.source="appArea.qml"
                var appArea = appAreaLoader.item.createObject(mainMenu);
                hide()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you will need to do the same for successive windows ...etc.
While for `result`, you need to use a `MouseArea`:

appArea.qml:

```
Component {
    id:  appMenu
    Window {
        id:appMenuWindow
        title: "App Menu"
        width: 600
        height: 600
        visible: true
        flags: Qt.Dialog
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        Loader{
            id:anotherLoader
            visible: true
            anchors.left: appMenuText.left
            anchors.top: appMenuText.bottom
            width: parent.width/3
            height: parent.height/3
        }
        Text {
            id: appMenuText
            text: "This is App Area"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
        Button{
            id: loadResult
            text: "Show Result"
            onClicked: {
                anotherLoader.source = "result.qml"
                anotherLoader.visible=true
            }
        }
        Button{
            anchors.right: parent.right
            id: loadMainMenu
            text: "Open main Menu"
            onClicked: {
                hide()
                //mmenu.show()
                anotherLoader.setSource("main.qml")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result.qml:

```
   Rectangle{

        color: "green"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            id: resultxt
            text: qsTr("This is result, Click to close")
        }
        MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onClicked: { anotherLoader.visible = false

             }
         }
    }
```